# C error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

Tags: c, initialization, declaration, variable-length-array, constant-expression

I'm currently learning C language from youtube and this is one of the code about the 2D arrays:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int const columns = 3;
    int const rows = 2;
    int grades[rows][columns] = {
        {12, 23, 45},
        {64, 78, 89}
    };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", grades[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to run it, it shows the error "error: variable-sized object may not be initialized"

```
int grades[rows][columns] = {

      |     ^~~
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:8:10: warning: excess elements in array initializer

    8 |         {12, 23, 45},
      |          ^~
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:8:10: note: (near initialization for 'grades[0]')
```

So on and so forth. I can't figure it out and it keeps struggling me.

Comment: It is as the error says: this is not allowed by the C standard. If you are using Microsoft Visual C, you can't use VLAs at all.

Answer (score 2):

the code is `C` not `C++` so this:

```
int const columns = 3;
int const rows = 2;
int grades[rows][columns] = {
    {12, 23, 45},
    {64, 78, 89}
};
```

needs to be changed to:

```
#define COLUMNS 3
#define ROWS 2
int grades[ ROWS ][ COLUMNS ] = {
    {12, 23, 45},
    {64, 78, 89}
};
```

Comment: Or constexpr variables

Comment: Okay.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In C the size of a not variable length array shall be an integer constant expression that is defined the following way (The C Standard, 6.6 Constant expressions)

> 6 An integer constant expression117) shall have integer type and shall
> only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants,
> character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer
> constants, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of
> casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only
> convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an
> operand to the sizeof operator.

and (The C Standard, 6.7.6.2 Array declarators)

> 4. ...If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has
>    a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type;
>    otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type.

And at last (The C Standard, 6.7.9 Initialization)

> 3 The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of
> unknown size or a complete object type that is not a variable length
> array type.

So variables even with the qualifier const may not be used in an integer constant expression.

Thus in this declaration

```
int grades[rows][columns] = {
    {12, 23, 45},
    {64, 78, 89}
};
```

there is declared a variable length array that according to the last quote may not be initialized.

You have two approaches to define the sizes of the array. Either use defined preprocessor constants like

```
#define columns 3
#define rows 2
```

Or use enumeration constants like

```
enum { columns = 3, rows = 2 };
int grades[rows][columns] = {
    {12, 23, 45},
    {64, 78, 89}
};
```

Comment: Alright.. I get it. Thank you so much!